# How do restrict the Internet access for internal user to internet connection

Tags: vpn

we have one cisco switch which connected to one TP Link Wifi modem as you can see below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS1eB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDa1b.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyEMK.png)

So in our company almost 20 users are connected to internet the same time and when somebody download big files like video the bandwidth for other decrease So we need to find oud out How do we restrict the Internet access, for this problem?

could we establish one Internal VPN with username and password to connect via internet and have control on user download capacity and user internet speed if they exceed the download maximum capacity? Or any other software with simple and user friendly GUI?

We have also different OS which are  LInux, Windows, Android.

Thanks.

Comment: One method is  to  install a proxy server where you can set download and access profiles See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Monitoring_and_filtering)  then you require that all users configure that proxy server by blocking all direct internet access (except for traffic coming via the proxy server).

Answer (score 0):

you have two way : 1)you can install kerio control and add limited download for users for wifi and cable connection, or 2)you can download and install microtik router os and install that in your server and run hot spot and add users in that and run queue to restrict the internet access, way 1 is better and useful 
,in kerio you can set login page for access internet for users